# ReactJS routing onEnter replace issue

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I have 2 routes

```
{
    path: '/a/:aP1/:aP2/',
    component: APage,
    onEnter: (nextState, replace) => {
            replace({
                state: {
                    status: 301
                },
                pathname: `/b/${nextState.params.aP1}/${nextState.params.aP2}/`
            });
            
    }
},
{
    path: '/b/:bP1/:bP2/',
    component: BPage,
    onEnter: (nextState, replace) => {
            replace({
                state: {
                    status: 301
                },
                pathname: `/a/${nextState.params.bP1}/${nextState.params.bP2}/`
            });
            
    }
}
```

The issue is when I do redirect, it appends pathname to route path. So instead of this redirect `/a/p1/p2` I get this - `/b/a/p1/p2`. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

add leading points to the redirect pathname:
`'../a/blah-blah'`